# Show activity indicator with Alamofire router

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have created an Alamofire router to manage all my API calls as follows -

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://testapi.silive.in/api/"

    case getAll()

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        var method: HTTPMethod {
            switch self {
            case .getAll():
                return .get
            }


        }

        let url: URL = {
            let relativePath: String
            switch self {
            case .getAll():
                relativePath = "get_list_"
            }



            var url = URL(string: Router.baseURLString)
            url?.appendPathComponent(relativePath)
            return url!
        }()

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        let encoding = JSONEncoding.default
        return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)

    }
}

class APIManager {
    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()

    func getAllPapers() {
        Alamofire.request(Router.getAll()).responseString {
            response in
            if let recievedString = response.result.value {
                print(recievedString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in My view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, I want to call `APIManager.sharedInstance.getAllPapers()` and while the request executes an activity indicator needs to be shown.

The problem is that I can start the activity indicator before making the call to the method, but **how do I stop the indicator**. The completion block of the Alamofire request doesn't have access to the activityIndicator that is present in the VC.

Answer (score 2):

You can create ApiManagerDelegate/Notification or completion handler in your getAllPapers method

edited:
example of completion handler:

```
typealias Response = (String?) -> Void



class APIManager {
    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()

    func getAllPapers(completionHandler: Response) {
        Alamofire.request(Router.getAll()).responseString {
            response in

            if let recievedString = response.result.value {
                completionHandler(recievedString)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can use it like this

```
APIManager.sharedInstance.getAllPapers {
    (response) in
    print(response)
    self.activityIndicator .....
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code on how to do this. I am new to iOS development.